# After several times loading an object in THREE.js, the page crashes

Tags: json, three.js, overloading

I have a few buttons in my app which load a new object onto the scene when clicked. Below is the code being used for loading new objects:

```
character = new THREE.UCSCharacter();

var ucspath = "skinnedModel.json";

manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function(url, itemsLoaded, itemsTotal) {
   console.log(url, itemsLoaded, itemsTotal);
};

var onProgress = function (xhr){
   if(xhr.lengthComputable){
      var bar = 150;

      percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
      bar = Math.floor( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * bar );

      document.getElementById("bar").style.width = bar + "px";
   }
};

var loader = new THREE.XHRLoader(manager);
loader.crossOrigin = true;

loader.load(ucspath, function (text) {
   var config = JSON.parse(text);
   character.loadParts(config);
   avatar = character.root;
   avatar.name = "female"; 
   scene.add(avatar);
}, onProgress);
```

After clicking the button 10~12 times, the loading becomes increasingly slow and eventually the page crashes. I could not detect any unsual behavior using Chrome DevTools.

Is there something that needs to be done in order to load as many objects as desired without overloading the browser?

**[Update] Heap Snapshot**
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try to [take a heap snapshot](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling#basics_snapshot) after each click on a button?
Is it the same model that is loaded?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. There is a significant increase in the size of the snapshot for every click on the button. I updated the post with a picture of it. Still not sure what to do. All the models are very similar (humanoid avatars).

Comment: It seems that your models are pretty heavy, I wouldn't be surprise if Chrome crashes because of this.
Can you give an idea of the average size / polycount of your models?
Given that the models are very similar, would it be possible to reuse the same base model using `THREE.Mesh.clone()` for the other ones?

Comment: Chrome loads them quite fast actually. And the problem only happens after triggering the load function several times in a row.
Average size is 10MB.
They have around 21,000 vertices and 40,000 triangles.
They are similar in the sense that they are all humanoid avatars, but they have different faces.

Comment: Okay, 2 more questions : If you click just 1 time and then check the size of the heap every 15 sec, is there an increase? and : the crash occurs when a model finishes loading and is rendered or at any time during the loading?

Comment: 1. I just did the heap snapshot test every 15s and there are no increases without a click event. 
2. It crashes without loading/rendering the model. LoadManager does not display 100% and XHR object says Caution: request in not finished yet (in Chrome's Network tab)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137012/discussion-between-neeh-and-igor-almeida).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're facing a **performance issue** caused by your model file.

Fortunately, the problem of a having a huge model replicated with different traits is very common in the game industry so I can give you an hint though it's not that simple :

In your 3D editor, merge all of your different geometries into **one single model** and give to each of your model parts an easy name like `hair_01`, `head_02`, `beard_03`, ...

Load this model in your *Three.js* app just once. This is your **template model**.

Now, when you want to create a new model with a different appearance :

- Clone the template model ;
- Hide the parts you don't want ;
- Show the parts you want.

Here's an example of the idea :

```
var copy = template.clone();
copy.getObjectByName('head_01').visible = false;
copy.getObjectByName('head_02').visible = true;
scene.add(copy);
```

Cloning the model prevents the engine from duplicating all geometry data (*).

This is a picture of a single 3D model file from an existing game that contains every character geometries and switch them in runtime to give a humanoid various appearances.

[image: Packed geometries into one single file]

---

*See [`THREE.Mesh.clone()`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/objects/Mesh.js#L346)